# node.js use request make http calls to transfer the correct array format array

Tags: arrays, node.js, http, request

for example:
to transfer a obj to /localhost/transfer

```
var request = require('request');
var obj={ 
  tag: 'false',
  array: [ '3', '4', '5'] 
}

request.post({url:/localhost/transfer, form:obj},function(err,httpResponse,body){
            if(err){
                res.json({error:false});
            }else{
                res.json({error:true});
            }
        });
```

get obj

```
router.post('/transfer',function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.obj);

});
```

the console obj display:

```
{ tag: 'false',
  'array[0]': '3',
  'array[1]': '4',
  'array[2]': '5' }
```

How to send or receive data correctly? like this

```
 { 
      tag: 'false',
      array: [ '3', '4', '5'] 
    }
```

request: https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/transfer` endpoint receives `obj` as `'array[0]': '3', 'array[1]': '4', 'array[2]': '5'` because the `Content-Type` of the HTTP request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` -- in the `request.post()` option, `form` property is used.

In order to send JSON object to `/transfer`, the `Content-Type` should be `application/json`. In module [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), it can be implemented as below:

```
var request = require('request');

var obj={
  tag: 'false',
  array: [ '3', '4', '5']
};

// requestb.in URL is used here for example, but it can be replaced.
request({
  url: 'https://requestb.in/srp1bmsr',
  method: 'post',
  body: obj,
  json: true
}, function(err, response, body) {
  if(err){
    // deal with error.
  }else{
    // deal with success response.
  }
});
```

According to module request's [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), `body` and `json` in the code means:

> **body** - entity body for PATCH, POST and PUT requests. Must be a Buffer, String or ReadStream. If json is true, then body must be a JSON-serializable object.
>
> **json** - sets body to JSON representation of value and adds Content-type: application/json header. Additionally, parses the response body as JSON.

Comment: Why does not the document mention this part?

Comment: @AlbertChen Do you mean `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Actually, the `request` module document mentioned by providing a simple example. Please search "application/x-www-form-urlencoded (URL-Encoded Forms)" in the document page and you will get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set headers using the `headers` property.

```
request.post({
   url:/localhost/transfer,
   body: obj,
   json: true
},function(err,httpResponse,body){
    if(err){
        res.json({error:false});
    }else{
        res.json({error:true});
    }
});
```

You can also set `json: true`, then it will add the header automatically and also parse the response body as JSON.

Comment: @AlbertChen It's not working because `form` property is used in `request.post()` and `body` is missing. Also, please note it is not necessary to define `"content-type": "application/json"` here as `json: true` will add it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When sending you have to set JSON headers as the content type.

Send

```
let message = {
    tag: 'false',
    array: [ '3', '4', '5'] 
};

return this.http
      .post(url, message, new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}))
```

When receiving you have to use the JSON body parser to parse the req body. https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Receive

```
router.post('/signin', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.bod);           
});
```

Here I'm using express as my node server. In your app.js (server.js or whatever main script) set the body parser to parse JSON payloads.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers,Forgot to mention that I am using this kit, which seems to have similar functionality, but I do not know how to use

Comment: It's for client side right? What are you using for server side?

Comment: Do you redirect the request to another server? Ok. Now what is your problem? Didn't my answer help?